# NuGet issue in azure automation

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to perform an automate a PowerShell script using Azure automation.

AzSK
AzSK enables us to run security health checks against our subscriptions or resource groups. The tool will give a report and also an option to automatically fix issues that are found.

[Below is the error which I am facing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI0kk.png)

Here is my code.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq7qc.png)

Get-AzSKSubscriptionSecurityStatus -SubscriptionId , will generate a report and I am trying to upload to azure storage. I works fine on my local machine. But here I am facing issue.

Any kind of help is really appreciated.

Regards,
Ashish D

Answer (score 0):

**AzCopy** module doesn't work in an azure automation runbook.

If you want to use **AzCopy** in your runbook you have to use the **[Hybrid Runbook Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker)**. In Hybrid Runbook Worker have compatibility to use .exe files. Using **Hybrid Runbook Worker** we can use **AzCopy** exe file to place in a Hybrid Worker and we can utilize the **AzCopy** script.

As of now we have [start-azstorageblobcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/start-azstorageblobcopy?view=azps-8.2.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-8.0.0#syntax) script to copy the files form one blob to another. But if we want to add some files to blob, we have to use the Hybrid Runbook Worker.

Refer [olufemiaMSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/90427/azure-powershell-runbooks-with-azure-storage.html) answer to add file to azure storage.